# Find an upper bound on the absolute error of 3.141 as an approximation to π

Tags: analysis, approximation

Q: Find an upper bound on the absolute error of 3.141 as an approximation to π

I have no idea what to do...  :(

What I know: absolute error = real value - approximate value

Help :)

Comment: This seems like it's missing a lot of context and details: What techniques do you have available? How have you defined $\pi$ and how are you approximating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a convergent alternating series, the sum of the series is between any two consecutive partial sums.  Using this idea and the [Leibiniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80), you can get arbitrarily precise upper and lower bounds on the value of $\pi$.  You can then use these bounds to bound the error from 3.141.

Note that if you just need *any* upper bound, you can use the fact the $3<\pi<4$ to know that the error is less than $0.859$.